# How to drop element from named list without assignment?

Tags: r

Suppose I have a named list like

```
somelist <- list(a = 1, b = 5, c = 3)
```

I know that I can drop `somelist$b`, say, by assigning `NULL` to it:

```
somelist$b <- NULL
```

I suppose this is fine for interactive work, but not so much for programmatic work, because it forces the creation of otherwise superfluous variables.

---

For example, suppose that `foo(42)` evaluates to a list similar to `somelist` above, and that I want to pass the list resulting from dropping the `b` element from `foo(42)` to some other function `bar`.  In this case, applying the method shown above would require the following:

```
superfluous.variable <- foo(42)
superfluous.variable$b <- NULL
bar(superfluous.variable)
rm(superfluous.variable)
```

---

I'm looking for a way to pass to `bar` the modified results from `foo` that does not require these superfluous assignments.  The four lines above would collapse to a single line:

```
bar(drop.item.from.list(foo(42), item.to.drop = "b"))
```

Does R already have something like the hypothetical `drop.item.from.list` function above?

Comment: Can you try `bar(foo(42)[setdiff(names(somelist), "b")])`

Comment: Not relevant, but does `bar` accept a "list" with named elements and performs operations extracting items? Wouldn't it be more convenient to have explicit `bar` arguments in its definition?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do that removal on the fly with `replace()`

```
replace(somelist, "b", NULL)
# $a
# [1] 1
#
# $c
# [1] 3
```

It works for multiple variables as well ...

```
replace(somelist, c("a", "b"), NULL)
# $c
# [1] 3
```

So just wrap that in `bar()` and the original list remains intact.

Note:  I am not exactly sure what you are doing with `foo(42)` but you state that the resulting list takes a similar structure, so this should be fine for that.

Answer (score 3):

We can try with `setdiff`

```
bar(foo(42)[setdiff(names(somelist), "b")])
```

as the `setdiff` subsets the 'somelist'

```
somelist[setdiff(names(somelist), "b")]
#$a
#[1] 1

#$c
#[1] 3
```

We can also use this to subset for multiple variables

```
somelist[setdiff(names(somelist), c("a", "b"))]
#$c
#[1] 3
```